# Setting fetched data from API in state won't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

I'm trying to build a news/article website for education purposes using Django and ReactJS.

Currently, I've created an article model in Django and set up an API for ReactJS to talk to. Every article has a headline, image, content, featured and quickreads properties. featured and quickreads are boolean values. I've successfully set up my ReactJS component to fetch all the articles however, I'm having trouble filtering the articles that have `article.featured` as true and `article.quickreads` also as true. Currently my component has three states: articles, featured and quickreads. This is how it currently looks:

```
class Api extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      articles: null,
      featured: null,
      quickreads: null
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/articlesapi/").then(request => request.json()).then(response => this.setState({articles: response}))
    var featured = this.state.articles.filter(article => article.featured === true)
    var quickreads = this.state.articles.filter(article => article.quickreads === true)
    this.setState({featured: featured, quickreads: quickreads})
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <p>Hello  World</p>
    )
  }
}
```

Although the component gets all the articles it fails to update `featured` and `quickreads`. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'articles' of undefined at componentDidMount (eval at <anonymous>)...
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem but related to your code: You can reduce the amount of keystrokes typing your objects if they have the same property and value name. So instead of `this.setState({featured: featured, quickreads: quickreads})` you can do: `this.setState({featured, quickreads})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fetch` is asynchronous, and thus `articles` is not set (and is `null`) when you try to filter it to set state. Instead, wait until the data is fetched:

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/articlesapi/")
  .then(request => request.json())
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      articles: response
      featured: response.filter(article => article.featured === true),
      quickreads: response.filter(article => article.quickreads === true)
    });
  });
```

And filter and set state along with setting `articles` after the data is fetched. I would, though, only store `articles` in state, and filtering when you need to do you don't end up having to sync up all the arrays to make sure they have the same data.

Comment: Also you shouldn't duplicate data in your state. Give all your articles a unique id and only add the ids to your `featured` and `quickreads` to reference the article. Otherwise you will find yourself having to update multiple places when an article changes.

Comment: @trixn Or just have one single origin of data, and filter that when you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, now I'm having trouble displaying these articles in my render function. For example when i do {this.state.articles(article => <p> {article.headline } </p>)} . However, i get the error: Unexpected token, expected , (43:15) and points to this.state.article . Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @electro7912 Probably have a stray syntax error somewhere. Have you checked line 43, column 15

Comment: I did. You can view the code on https://gist.github.com/mtusman/19942b887392eb64c42c8ab2553fadfa#file-reactjs-api-error

Comment: @Andrew Li But that doesn't protect you from the updating problem. If you later decide that you want to be able to update a single article without mutating it (mutation is the source of all evil) then you will have to filter everything again or your `featured` and `quickreads` objects will be out of sync with your `articles`. Normalizing state from the very beginning keeps you out of trouble there.

Comment: @electro7912 The component will render before the fetch is done, check if featured is defined or not and maybe show a loading screen if it's not.

Comment: @trixn I see, and that's a completely valid statement, but unless they need to mutate an article, it's not completely necessary. But I did misunderstand your first comment and now I understand, you're correct.